# Having trouble extracting text from inside scraped html tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

The code I am using to scrape the content

```
class Scraper(object):
# contains methods to scrape data from curse

def scrape(url):
    req = request.Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    return request.urlopen(req).read()

def lookup(page, tag, class_name):
    parsed = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    return parsed.find_all(tag, class_=class_name)
```

This returns a list with entries similar to this

```
<li class="title"><h4><a href="/addons/wow/world-quest-tracker">World Quest Tracker</a></h4></li>
```

I'm attempting to extract  the text inbetween the href tags, in this instance

```
World Quest Tracker
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<li class="title"><h4><a href="/addons/wow/world-quest-tracker">World Quest Tracker</a></h4></li>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".title"):
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
World Quest Tracker
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html_doc = '<li class="title"><h4><a href="/addons/wow/world-quest-tracker">World Quest Tracker</a></h4></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print soup.find('a').text
```

this will print

> > u'World Quest Tracker'

Answer (score 0):

> I'm attempting to extract the text inbetween the href tags

If you actually want the text in the `href` attribute, and not the text content wrapped by the `<a></a>` anchor (your wording is a bit unclear), use `get('href')`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<li class="title"><h4><a href="/addons/wow/world-quest-tracker">World Quest Tracker</a></h4></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.find('a').get('href')

'/addons/wow/world-quest-tracker'
```